# MediaElementJS Audio Player Fails on First Load

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am experiencing a problem where the audio player fails to play on the first visit and/or an empty cache. The player will display with the controls, but will not play. The audio file is also not preloaded. If I reload the page, the audio will play fine. Also, on subsequent visits, the player will work as expected. But, if I empty my cache, the player will not play again.

I have tried updating the most current version (currently 2.6.1) and I am using jquery 2.7.1 (I had the same problem with 2.7.0 and 2.6.4). I am using Google's CDN to host the jquery, but I have experienced the same problem on a local version (it is in the same directory as the mediaelements.js and .css files, but it is a different subdomain because the site is django and the subdomain is where all my media assets are).

Is the some sort of cross domain issue with having the jquery file or mediaelement.js file in a different subdomain?

You can see this behavior by clicking one of the stream links on http://www.audiodharma.org/

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and i can see in your site that you solved it. can you please share the solution ?